# The code below uses the method lastIndexOf. Why does the code after reaching the position = 0, it starts to printf infinitely?

Tags: javascript

```js
let str = "as time flies asses start as if there as";
let target = "as";
pos = str.length;
while ((pos = str.lastIndexOf(target, pos-1)) != -1) {
    console.log( pos );
    if (pos == 0) break; //Why does commenting this causes the infinite loop?
}
```

If we comment the 
`if (pos == 0) break;`
the code runs infinitely. Why is this happening? Why doesn't code after reaching the `pos == 0` stop automatically?

Comment: This happens since at last iteration `pos` is always set to `0` and thus `0 != 1` evaluates true always and the loop runs infinitely

Comment: @palash why is that always set to `0`?

Comment: This happens as `lastIndexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])` method returns the index within the calling String object of the last occurrence of the specified value, searching backwards from `fromIndex` and it only returns `-1` only if the value is not found and as `target` exists in `str`.. thus value is always 0 even if the `fromIndex` < 0.

Comment: Here, `fromIndex` is optional and it is the index of the last character in the string to be considered as the beginning of a match. The default value is `+Infinity`. If `fromIndex >= str.length`, the whole string is searched. If `fromIndex < 0`,  the behaviour will be the same as if it would be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the parameter descriptions for lastIndexOf:

```
Parameter          Description 
item               The item to search for

start              Where to start the search. Negative values will start
                   at the given position counting from the end, and search to 
                   the  beginning
```

1. The last "real" loop results in 0 as it finds the target at the very beginning of the string.
2. Then you call lastIndexOf with 0-1. Negative values result in going backwards from the end to the beginning. Pos is then 0 once again.
3. Go back to #1. Repeat as many times as you wish, it will still be 0.

Your problem is that `str.lastIndexOf(target, -1)` is bascially an `indexOf`, so you get the very first occurrence at 0.

No need to show you working code, as you have already got that: Get out of the loop when the position is 0.

Comment: I have the target at `pos = 0`. But after reaching that why doesn't the `pos` becomes negative i.e. `pos = -1`?

Answer (score 0):

I stand corrected, my last answer (deleted to avoid confusion) wasn't accounting for the updation of the value of `pos`, but with that clarity, the answer is very obvious.

The last value for `pos` is 0. In the next loop, you calculate the value as `lastIndex(target, -1)` which will always give you 0 as you ask to start searching from position -1.

Comment: Why is that it will be `0` only?